# Flask-login get_id override prevents other methods from working

Tags: flask, overriding, flask-login

I'm trying to override the **get_id** method in Flask-login so that I can use an alternate id in the session cookie (per Flask docs). The class code I have is as follows:

```
class Users(UserMixin,db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    alt_id = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False,unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20),nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20),nullable=False,unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(256),nullable=False)
    
    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.alt_id)
```

.. and the load_user functions is as follows:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(alt_id):
return Users.query.get(alt_id)
```

I also have a simple test route. the idea is to check if current_user is authenticated and return something if True or else try and log user in. Code as follows:

```
@app.route('/<username>')
def login(username):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return f"{current_user.username} already logged in"
    user = Users.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    login_user(user)
    return f"{current_user.username} is now logged in"
```

The problem is that overriding the **get_id** method breaks all the other UserMixin methods. The above will never show the first return statement even though it is successfully logging the user in (I've checked the session cookie is being created and have decoded it and it has all the info needed).

So going to 127.0.0.1/myuser would first show the second return statement, a refresh then shows the first return statement because the user is authenticated. This does not happen, it always shows the second return statement as if the is_authenticated test has failed.

I've used the exact same code without overriding the get_id and everything works as it should. I've also tried not using the UserMixin and defining the methods manually with the same non-working results.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as I am not getting any errors.

Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by using an alternate user id?

Comment: Per the Flask-login docs. If the user changes passwords I would have to change the user's primary user id to invalidate any remember me session cookies. It also means that the users cannot see the DBs primary keys. The alternative ids are generated randomly.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken another look at the docs and my code and have solved the problem.

It turns out I was using th incorrect SQLAlchemy statement. The **get** method of the `Users.query.get(id)`line in **load_user** is for selecting by primary key only. Of course, I was feeding the function the alt_id so it was returning a None object. Changing the query to `Users.query.filter_by(alt_id=alt_id).first()` solved the problem.